# How to add a common box shadow to the contents of a div in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created two adjacent `<input>` fields to create the following effect of prefixing country code before phone number input:

[image]

Here is the code for the same:

```
       <input
          value="+91"
          style={{
             backgroundColor: "#E1E7EC",
             width: "30px",
             height: "48px",
             borderRight: "none",
             color: "#8895A7",
             fontSize: 16,
             borderColor: this.state.inputborder,
             borderWidth: this.state.inputborderwidth
          }}
          readOnly
       />
       <input
          style={{
             backgroundColor: "#E1E7EC",
             width: "368.02px",
             height: "48px",
             borderLeft: "none",
             color: "#8895A7",
             fontSize: 16,
             borderColor: this.state.inputborder,
             borderWidth: this.state.inputborderwidth
          }}
          name="phone"
          id="phone"
          value={this.state.phone}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          placeholder="Enter 10 digit mobile number"
          maxLength="10"
       />
```

I wanted to add a common box shadow around both these inputs. I tried wrap these inputs inside a `div` and added a common box shadow to `div` like this:

```
    <div
       style={{
          boxShadow: "inset 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
          display: "inline-block"
       }}
    >
       <input
          value="+91"
          style={{
             backgroundColor: "#E1E7EC",
             width: "30px",
             height: "48px",
             borderRight: "none",
             color: "#8895A7",
             fontSize: 16,
             borderColor: this.state.inputborder,
             borderWidth: this.state.inputborderwidth
          }}
          readOnly
       />
       <input
          style={{
             backgroundColor: "#E1E7EC",
             width: "368.02px",
             height: "48px",
             borderLeft: "none",
             color: "#8895A7",
             fontSize: 16,
             borderColor: this.state.inputborder,
             borderWidth: this.state.inputborderwidth
          }}
          name="phone"
          id="phone"
          value={this.state.phone}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          placeholder="Enter 10 digit mobile number"
          maxLength="10"
       />
    </div>
```

But this is not showing the desired results. How to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the both `input`'s wrapped in a div and apply shadow to that like:

```css
.shadow {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
  <p>You can display your inputs right here</p>
</div>
```